# How to use normalize JSON timeseries with pandas with identical column names

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to consume an api with time series data which has the following format:

```
...
"value":[
{
"Key":"bt386",
"ReferenceDate":"2019-07-27T00:00:00Z",
"TargetDate":"2019-07-28T00:00:00Z",
"PublicationDate":null,
"ChangedOn":"2019-07-27T09:36:03.9727098+01:00",
"ValidUntil":"9999-12- 
31T23:59:59.9999999Z",
"ValueColumnsNumber":[ 
{"Key":"FreshSnowDepth","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"Precipitation","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"RainSnowMelt","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"Runoff","Value":31.800000000}, 
{"Key":"SnowDepth","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"SnowDepthNormalPerc","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"SnowMelt","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"SnowWaterEquivalents","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"Temperature","Value":18.450000000}],"ValueColumnsText": 
[],"ValueColumnsDateTime":[]},
{
"Key":"bt386",
"ReferenceDate":"2019-07-27T00:00:00Z",
"TargetDate":"2019-07-29T00:00:00Z",
"PublicationDate":null,
"ChangedOn":"2019-07- 
27T09:36:03.9727098+01:00",
"ValidUntil":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z",
"ValueColumnsNumber":[ 
{"Key":"FreshSnowDepth","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"Precipitation","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"RainSnowMelt","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"Runoff","Value":28.400000000}, 
{"Key":"SnowDepth","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"SnowDepthNormalPerc","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"SnowMelt","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"SnowWaterEquivalents","Value":0.000000000}, 
{"Key":"Temperature","Value":18.750000000}],
"ValueColumnsText": 
[],
"ValueColumnsDateTime":[]
}
]
```

I tried the following code:

```
d = json.loads(response.content)
timeSeries = json_normalize(data=d['value'], 
record_path='ValueColumnsNumber',
meta=['ReferenceDate', 'TargetDate'])

table = timeSeries.pivot_table('Value', ['ReferenceDate', 'TargetDate'], 
'Key')
table.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

print(table.head(3))

Key         ReferenceDate            TargetDate  FreshSnowDepth
0    2017-03-22T00:00:00Z  2017-03-23T00:00:00Z             2.8   
1    2017-03-22T00:00:00Z  2017-03-24T00:00:00Z             7.6   
2    2017-03-22T00:00:00Z  2017-03-25T00:00:00Z             0.3
```

What I would need is to also include the alphanumeric key.

```
Key       CurveKey       ReferenceDate            TargetDate  FreshSnowDepth
0         bt386   2017-03-22T00:00:00Z  2017-03-23T00:00:00Z             2.8   
1         bt386   2017-03-22T00:00:00Z  2017-03-24T00:00:00Z             7.6   
2         abcde   2017-03-22T00:00:00Z  2017-03-25T00:00:00Z             0.3  

 timeSeries = json_normalize(data=d['value'], 
 record_path='ValueColumnsNumber',
 meta=['Key', 'ReferenceDate', 'TargetDate'])
```

When I change the `json_normalize()` function I get the following error:

"ValueError: Conflicting metadata name Key, need distinguishing prefix"

What do I need to do in order to transform the json into the desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
table = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, ['value', 'ValueColumnsNumber'], meta=[
    ['value', 'Key'],
    ['value', 'ReferenceDate'],
    ['value', 'TargetDate'],
])
```

`record_path` should be the deepest level that you want to loop over. `meta` contains anything at the shallower levels that you want to grab along.

Result:

```
              Key  Value value.Key   value.ReferenceDate      value.TargetDate
0  FreshSnowDepth    0.0     bt386  2019-07-27T00:00:00Z  2019-07-28T00:00:00Z
1   Precipitation    0.0     bt386  2019-07-27T00:00:00Z  2019-07-28T00:00:00Z
2    RainSnowMelt    0.0     bt386  2019-07-27T00:00:00Z  2019-07-28T00:00:00Z
3          Runoff   31.8     bt386  2019-07-27T00:00:00Z  2019-07-28T00:00:00Z
4       SnowDepth    0.0     bt386  2019-07-27T00:00:00Z  2019-07-28T00:00:00Z
```